# How to use connector of mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, connector

I want to use connector for mysql data base. I am follow this page

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html

But it seems hard . Is there any other tutorial present. Please let me know.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html    its working properly. can you please give some easy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the relevant part of the example code is pretty simple:

```
     Driver *driver;
     Connection *con;
     Statement *stmt;
     ResultSet *res;

    driver = get_driver_instance();

    /* create a database connection using the Driver */
    con = driver -> connect(url, user, password);

    /* alternate syntax using auto_ptr to create the db connection */
    //auto_ptr  con (driver -> connect(url, user, password));

    /* turn off the autocommit */
    con -> setAutoCommit(0);

    /* select appropriate database schema */
    con -> setSchema(database);
```

From there on you just have to query it like so:

```
     stmt = con -> createStatement();

     res = stmt -> executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM City");
```

Comment: after all this, we have to compile with cc: sun c++ compiler. Can not we run with g++ compiler.